# Updating of property values & bindings in .NET MAUI ContentView

Tags: data-binding, maui, contentview

I'm attempting to try my hand at creating a card-based UI similar to Android's [`CardView`](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/cardview) layout using MAUI [`ContentView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/contentview?view=net-maui-7.0). The exemplary use case for such an element is the display of testing or scoring results, so I attempted to roll in some of the underlying logic directly into the new element - the user would simply have to supply an `Attempted` and a `Possible` set of integers, i.e. `92` and `100`, from which it would display an "out-of" format of `92/100` as well as a percentage of `92.0%`.

The issue is that I've tried a number of ways to do this, and none successfully update the `Score` and `Percentage` properties correctly. I realize that it may be an issue with the order (or simultaneity) of the properties being set, but I haven't been able to rectify it using `BindableProperty.Create(..., propertyChanged:)` or other methods.

`ProgressViewCard.xaml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView x:Name="this"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ExampleApp.Controls.ProgressCardView">
    <Frame BindingContext="{x:Reference this}" BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}" CornerRadius="5" HasShadow="True">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="3*"   />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"   />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"  />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"  />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!-- Configure the button functionality of the ProgressCardView -->
            <Button x:Name="InternalButton" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0.0" Clicked="buttonEvent" />

            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="17" TextColor="{Binding HeaderColor}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Score}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="12" TextColor="{Binding TextColor}" />
            <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HeightRequest="1" Color="{Binding TextColor}"/>
            <ProgressBar x:Name="CardProgressBar" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Percentage}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="12" TextColor="{Binding TextColor}" />
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</ContentView>
```

`ProgressViewCard.xaml.cs`:

```
namespace ExampleApp.Controls
{
    public partial class ProgressCardView : ContentView
    {
        private int attempted  = 0;
        private int possible   = 0;

        #region BindableProperties

        public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(Title), 
            typeof(string), 
            typeof(ProgressCardView2), 
            string.Empty);

        public static readonly BindableProperty AttemptedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(Attempted),
            typeof(int),
            typeof(ProgressCardView2),
            0);

        public static readonly BindableProperty PossibleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(Possible),
            typeof(int),
            typeof(ProgressCardView2),
            1);

        public static readonly BindableProperty BackgroundColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(BackgroundColor), 
            typeof(Color), 
            typeof(ProgressCardView2), 
            Color.FromArgb("#FFFFFF"));

        public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(HeaderColor), 
            typeof(Color), 
            typeof(ProgressCardView2), 
            Color.FromArgb("#FFFFFF"));

        public static readonly BindableProperty TextColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(TextColor), 
            typeof(Color), 
            typeof(ProgressCardView2), 
            Color.FromArgb("#FFFFFF"));

        #endregion

        #region Getters and Setters

        public string Title 
        {
            get => (string) GetValue(ProgressCardView2.TitleProperty);
            set => SetValue(ProgressCardView2.TitleProperty, value);
        }

        public int Attempted
        {
            get => (int) GetValue(ProgressCardView2.AttemptedProperty);
            set => SetValue(ProgressCardView2.AttemptedProperty, value);
        }

        public int Possible
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(ProgressCardView2.PossibleProperty);
            set => SetValue(ProgressCardView2.PossibleProperty, value);
        }

        public string Score
        {
            get { return String.Format("{0}/{1}", this.attempted, this.possible); }
            set { this.Score = value; }
        }

        public string Percentage
        {
            get { return String.Format("{0:P1}", ((double) this.attempted) / ((double) this.possible)); }
            set { this.Score = value; }
        }

        public Color BackgroundColor
        {
            get => (Color) GetValue(ProgressCardView2.BackgroundColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(ProgressCardView2.BackgroundColorProperty, value);
        }

        public Color HeaderColor
        {
            get => (Color) GetValue(ProgressCardView2.HeaderColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(ProgressCardView2.HeaderColorProperty, value);
        }

        public Color TextColor
        {
            get => (Color) GetValue(ProgressCardView2.TextColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(ProgressCardView2.TextColorProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods and Events

        public ProgressCardView2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

The usage of the controls is as follows:

```
<ctrls:ProgressCardView Title="CS 101 Final"   Attempted="92" Possible="100" BackgroundColor="#ffffff" 
                        HeaderColor="#e74c3c" TextColor="#7f8c8d" />
<ctrls:ProgressCardView Title="ME 302 Midterm" Attempted="68" Possible="85"  BackgroundColor="#ffffff" 
                        HeaderColor="#e74c3c" TextColor="#7f8c8d" />
```

[image: Screenshot of undesired custom MAUI control behavior]

This is the result in an Android emulator (API 31). How do I modify the above control to obtain the correct behavior?

Comment: I think you are saying that when Attempted or Possible are set, then Score and Percentage should update? This won't happen unless the setters of Attempted and Possible say what OTHER properties are affected. In Xamarin that was `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Score));` etc. Not sure exact syntax for Maui.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve That’s correct - I’ll try looking into the specifics of MAUI BindableProperties and update here if that resolves it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have done most of the work. I tried your code and made some changes which worked for me.

**First**, in Custom control **ProgressCardView**, delete this first two lines:

```
private int attempted  = 0;
private int possible   = 0;
```

because this has nothing to do with the **BindableProperty** and you use the following code which will cause the value always be 0. You could set default value in **BindableProperty.Create**.

```
public string Score
{
    get { return String.Format("{0}/{1}", this.attempted, this.possible); } 
}
```

**Second**, in BindableProperty, you could define propertyChanged event handler, which could  define a callback method when property changed. For more info, you could refer to [Detect property changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties?view=net-maui-7.0#detect-property-changes)

And for your case, the change of **AttemptedProperty** and **PossibleProperty** would cause the result changed, so we could add propertyChanged to these two BindableProperty. Such like the following:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty AttemptedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(Attempted),
    typeof(int),
    typeof(ProgressViewCard),
    0,
    propertyChanged:OnThisPropertyChanged);

public static readonly BindableProperty PossibleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(Possible),
    typeof(int),
    typeof(ProgressViewCard),
    1,
    propertyChanged:OnThisPropertyChanged);
```

For convenience, I think these two properties could share the same propertyChanged callback method, that's to count the value.

Then we could implement the OnThisPropertyChanged callback method:

```
private static void OnThisPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var myCard = bindable as ProgressViewCard;
    myCard.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Score));
    myCard.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Percentage));
}
```

***Here is the complete code for ProgressViewCard.cs which worked for me:***

```
#region BindableProperties

public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(Title),
    typeof(string),
    typeof(ProgressViewCard),
    string.Empty);

public static readonly BindableProperty AttemptedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(Attempted),
    typeof(int),
    typeof(ProgressViewCard),
    0,
    propertyChanged:OnThisPropertyChanged);

public static readonly BindableProperty PossibleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(Possible),
    typeof(int),
    typeof(ProgressViewCard),
    1,
    propertyChanged:OnThisPropertyChanged);

private static void OnThisPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var a = bindable as ProgressViewCard;
    a.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Score));
    a.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Percentage));
}


public static readonly BindableProperty BackgroundColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(BackgroundColor),
    typeof(Color),
    typeof(ProgressViewCard),
    Color.FromArgb("#FFFFFF"));

public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(HeaderColor),
    typeof(Color),
    typeof(ProgressViewCard),
    Color.FromArgb("#FFFFFF"));

public static readonly BindableProperty TextColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(TextColor),
    typeof(Color),
    typeof(ProgressViewCard),
    Color.FromArgb("#FFFFFF"));

#endregion

#region Getters and Setters

public string Title
{
    get => (string)GetValue(ProgressViewCard.TitleProperty);
    set => SetValue(ProgressViewCard.TitleProperty, value);
}

public int Attempted
{
    get => (int)GetValue(ProgressViewCard.AttemptedProperty);
    set => SetValue(ProgressViewCard.AttemptedProperty, value);
}

public int Possible
{
    get => (int)GetValue(ProgressViewCard.PossibleProperty);
    set => SetValue(ProgressViewCard.PossibleProperty, value);
}

public string Score
{
    get { return String.Format("{0}/{1}", this.Attempted, this.Possible); }
    set { this.Score = value; }
}

public string Percentage
{
    get { return String.Format("{0:P1}", ((double)this.Attempted) / ((double)this.Possible)); }
    set { this.Score = value; }
}

public Color BackgroundColor
{
    get => (Color)GetValue(ProgressViewCard.BackgroundColorProperty);
    set => SetValue(ProgressViewCard.BackgroundColorProperty, value);
}

public Color HeaderColor
{
    get => (Color)GetValue(ProgressViewCard.HeaderColorProperty);
    set => SetValue(ProgressViewCard.HeaderColorProperty, value);
}

public Color TextColor
{
    get => (Color)GetValue(ProgressViewCard.TextColorProperty);
    set => SetValue(ProgressViewCard.TextColorProperty, value);
}

#endregion

#region Methods and Events

public ProgressViewCard()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void buttonEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

#endregion
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: It worked! I had tried implementing the `propertyChanged:` callback before, but it looks like I was getting the implementation a bit wrong - particularly the `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(...))` bits. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for this response. It worked for me as well. As a note, I think the "set" accessor in Score and Percentage are not needed here.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative with less coding. Don't need propertyChanged methods.

Just add OnPropertyChanged lines to the `set` methods:

```cs
public int Possible
{
    get => (int)GetValue(ProgressCardView2.PossibleProperty);
    set {
        if (SetValue(ProgressCardView2.PossibleProperty, value)) {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Score));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Percentage));
        }
    }
}
```

Repeat for `Attempted`.

Either approach works fine.